# Having a Click and Keydown action do one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Javascript game, 
I want to be able to press "Enter" to start the game,
or press the Start button in-game to start the game.

I know how to have multiple selectors for a click function,
but how would I implement the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this 
HTML

```
<button>Click or keydown?</button>
```

Script

```
$('button').bind("click keydown", function (evt) {
    if (evt.type == "keydown" && evt.which == 13)
        alert("Key 13 pressed");
    else if (evt.type == "click")
        alert("Clicked!");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bymug/4/)

OR

```
function game(e) { 
 alert('game start'); 
 }

$('#YourStartButtonID').click(function(e) { 
    game(e);
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { game(e); }
});​​​
```

Comment: This only works when the button is focused, and most of the times the focus will be on `<canvas>` or `document`.

Comment: So is having two separate ways of running a single action the only way? If possible, I want to do something like:

$('#YourStartButtonID').click.or.keydown(function(e) { 
    game(e);
});

Answer (score 1):

```
function startGame(){ /*...*/ }        //Your game-starter

$("#start").click(startGame);          //Button
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) startGame();   //Enter key
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#btn').bind('click',function(){alert(1);});
  });
    $(document).bind("keydown",function(){if(event.keyCode==13)alert(1);});
  </script>
```